# Analytic change of free energy after renormalization

Tags: statistical-mechanics, renormalization, critical-phenomena, scaling

Suppose we have some model in statistical physics with Hamiltonian $H$ and partition function
$$Z=\mathrm{Tr}\left(e^{-H}\right) $$

the free energy per site is defined as

$$ f =\frac1N\log Z$$

A renormalization transformation is applied, and now the model has a new Hamiltonian $H'$. By definition the RG has to leave the partition function invariant, nevertheless it can introduce constants in the Hamiltonian that can then be absorbed in a "new" partition function

$$e^{-H}\mapsto e^{-H' + G} $$

hence the new state is $$ \frac{1}{Z}e^{G}e^{-H'}=\frac{1}{Z'}e^{-H'}$$

with $Z'=Ze^{-G}$, and the new free energy is

$$f'=\frac{1}{N'}\log Z'=b^{d}\log Z-b^d G=b^d f-b^d G $$

where $b$ is the scaling factor of the RG and $d$ the dimensionality of the system. It is often said that this addition $G$ to the free energy is analytical, this is sometimes phrased as "the singular part of the free energy does not change under renormalization". For example in Cardy's book "Scaling and Renormalization in Statistical Physics", page 45

> If we are interested in extracting the singular behaviour of $f$,[...], we may in fact drop the inhomogeneous $g$ term. Physically, this is because it originates from summing over the short wavelength degrees of freedom within each block, so that $g({K})$ should be an analytic function of the $K_\alpha$, even at the critical point.

I was wondering if there was a more mathematical explanation or a reference that provides a more extensive justification. I couldn't find one anywhere, and I feel that a lot hinges on this fact.